# Solve $\int_{0}^{1} \log(x)\log(1-x) dx$ without convolution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Maybe it's too much to ask for, but is there a way to solve $\int \limits_{0}^{1} \log(x)\log(1-x) dx$ without convolution?

Note that $\log x =\log_e x$.

Comment: Is $log(x)$ here used as simply as that or $log|x|$?

Comment: $x$ and $1-x$ are non-negative numbers in the integration range, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I wanted to try to use $x=-t$ , but seems unless anyway. Nvm

Comment: You can still do it. The argument of the $\log$ will remain positive so you can use $\log|x|$ instead of $\log(x)$ if it will help you solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1:** We prove that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $$\int_{0}^{1} x^n \log(x) \, dx = -\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ Starting with the identity $$\int_{0}^{1} x^n \, dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$$ differentiate both sides with respect to $n$ to get the desired result.

**Step 2:** Expanding $\log(1-x)$ as its Taylor series, we have $$\log(x)\log(1-x) = -x\log(x) - \frac{x^2 \log(x)}{2} - \frac{x^3 \log(x)}{3} - \cdots$$ Sweeping issues of convergence under the rug, integrating both sides over the interval $[0,1]$ gives $$\int_{0}^{1} \log(x) \log(1-x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^2} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4^2} + \cdots$$
**Step 3:** We must evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \right)$$ $$ = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} = 1 - \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1\right) = 2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: That was genius! Thank you.

Comment: To be quite picky, $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ is not trivial here.  But no doubt it is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Integrating by parts we find:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[x\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}x\left[\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}-\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{x\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}-\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x-2\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1-t\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[1-x=t\right]}\\
&=2-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=2-\frac{\pi^2}{6},\\
\end{align}$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(z\right)}$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

Comment: In the second line, $[x\ln (x)\ln(1-x)]^1_0$ gets evaluated as $0-0$ i.e. for $x=1$ we are writing, $1\times \ln(1)\times \ln(0)$. In other words, $ 0 \times -\infty =  0$. Is it valid ?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath Yes. One way to demonstrate this is by Taylor expanding the $\ln{(x)}$ factor about $x=1$. You could also use l'Hoptial's rule of course.